# Are all 3-point-perspective-like figures legal?

Tags: geometry

I have a 3-point perspective of a cuboid, randomly drawn like this.

[image]

Question 1:

It looks like a valid perspective view of a cuboid for me, but are arbitrary 3-point-perspective-like cuboid figures valid?

Question 2:

It doesn't look like a cube. What rules do I need to determine if it is a right 3-point-perspective figure of a cube?

Comment: You could have 1, 2 or even 3 of the "spikes" sent to infinity, generating parallel lines.